# Getting the object using one of it's property's values

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a json that, lets say it looks something like this:

```
[
  {
  "name":"Foo"
  "nickname":"Lorem Ipsum"
  },
  {
  "name":"Bar"
  "nickname":"Dolor Sit"
  }
]
```

Now, i want to find the nickname of something using the value of nickname to find it. Is there a way to do this in JavaScript? If so, how?

Comment: Yes, of course it is. Have you tried anything at all? Searched for "How to find objects in javascript", or made any attempt at this?

Comment: This isn't a valid JSON. You probably meant to use square brackets (`[]`) at the beginning and the end to create a list of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the input should be corrected in a way pointed out in my comment to be a proper and correct JSON, this function will serve the purpose.

```js
function findByName(name) {
  const i = [{
      "name": "Foo",
      "nickname": "Lorem Ipsum"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bar",
      "nickname": "Dolor Sit"
    }
  ]
  
  return i.find(e => e.name === name).nickname;
}

const res = findByName("Foo"); // ==> "Lorem Ipsum"
console.log(res);
```